# jQuery colorbox plugin passing values from iFrame to parent onCleanup event

Tags: jquery, colorbox

In the parent I have:

```
$.colorbox({width:"400px", height:"400px", iframe:true, href:"test.html"});
```

So in my iFrame I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.parent.$.bind("cbox_cleanup", function() {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

This is is all in an effort to transfer a value, that is set in the iFrame, to the parent when the user closes the colorbox by the action of clicking outside the colorbox boundary. The above does not fire though although I don't get any error.

Many thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Try just `parent.$.bind(...)`. Although, since you own the page, I assume, you could drill down into the iFrame from the cbox_cleanup and get the value. If you do not own the page, it will not be possible due to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) From an UI/UX side though, you do want to avoid using frames for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Set your event in colorbox options.

```
$.colorbox({
    width:"400px",
    height:"400px",
    iframe:true,
    href:"test.html",
    onCleanup: function() {
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

Just a info, `onCleanup` fires when when starts the close process.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I tried parent.bind but still no luck. The reason I'm trying to bind the event hook from within the iFrame rather than use a callback from the parent is that the user is setting a value in the iFrame that I want to pass back to the parent. I could use a callback and try and use the jQuery data() method to attach the user value to the iFrame I guess...

Comment: It turns out that this works:

`parent.$(parent.document).bind("cbox_cleanup", function() {
        //do something here
    });`
Although it only works the first time. Successive opening of the colorbox results in the parent being undefined so I'm guessing I need to unbind somewhere!